# Disable shinydashboard menuItem serverside using disable function from shinyjs

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I cant seem to get a menuItem selection to disable / greyout from the server side based on tabName.

Any input?

Thanks.

Comment: It can be helpful to give us some base code to help reproduce the problem and come up with a solution. It's also of value to show what you have tried already, or what research you have done to try and solve this.

Comment: Not needed, title and description clearly states what i'm asking.